# Android: How to reduce the clickable area of View?

Tags: android

I have two images whose transparent area are overlapping with each other. When i am clicking 
one image , the onclicklistener of another image gets called. Is there anyway to reduce the clickable area of ImageView.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the OnClickListener, but the [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) and handle the click area by yourself.

For example by scaling the touch rectangle and translating it to the center of the view.
You could also use radius or manual offsets.

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        final Rect rect = new Rect();
        v.getHitRect(rect);

        float scale = 0.5f;

        final float x = event.getX();
        final float y = event.getY();

        final float minX = v.getWidth() * 0.5f * (1.0f - scale);
        final float maxX = v.getWidth() * 0.5f * (1.0f + scale);

        final float minY = v.getHeight() * 0.5f * (1.0f - scale);
        final float maxY = v.getHeight() * 0.5f * (1.0f + scale);

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (x > minX && x < maxX && y > minY && y < maxY) {
                    Log.d("TOUCH", String.valueOf(x) + " " + String.valueOf(y));
            }
            break;

        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You create a [`TouchDelegate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TouchDelegate.html) :

```
final View parent = (View) findViewById(R.id.touch_delegate_root); 
parent.post( new Runnable() {
    // Post in the parent's message queue to make sure the parent
    // lays out its children before we call getHitRect()
    public void run() {
        final Rect rect = new Rect();
        Button delegate = YourActivityClass.this.mButton;
        delegate.getHitRect(rect);
        rect.top -= 20;
        rect.bottom += 12;  // etc 
        parent.setTouchDelegate( new TouchDelegate( rect , delegate));
    }
});
```

<sub>refered from [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/178af525ab84b371)</sub>

Comment: With your method i was able to increase the touchable area, but i was not able to reduce the area.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it using xml only. Just put your image in a frame and place another transparent view that you wire to click events on top of it. Adjust size and position with layout parameters:

```
<FrameLayout
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <ImageView android:id="your_view"
  android:clickable="false"
  <!-- your other attributes -->
  <!-- ... -->
  />
  <ImageView android:id="the_clickable_view"
      android:src="@null"
  <!-- set desired size of clickable area -->
  <!-- align it inside a frame using:
  android:gravity and android:margins -->
  />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: As the desired non-clickable area is a "transparent" one (I assume that means it's not within the drawable's area) you could even ditch the added view and just by adding the FrameLayout you solved it - use the original layout attributes on the FrameLayout instead of the ImageView and make the ImageView only as big as you want it clickable.